# Different Types of Routes in Zend Framework

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

I have been stumbling upon Zend Framework 2 and all I could find information about the route types is only for 'segment', especially from the Album module example from [Zend Framework 2 official site](http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html)

Is it possible for some one to give me more information about the different types of routes that can be used, in which case what route type should be used. Information including with some basic examples would be more informative.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this introducing could help you:

http://evan.pro/zf2-router-talk.html

Answer (score 0):

This might help for somebody if still want to know about route types in ZF2
http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html